# Sniffer - How to link the GET requests with their response?

Tags: http, tcp, packet-sniffers

I have a function that gets all packets (in and out). I'm monitoring for GET and HTTP 200 OK. All works fine, but how to link the GET request with its OK response?

EDIT:
I want to know how to do it programically. I know that professional sniffers can 'follow traffic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the source and destination ports of the request and response to link it to the same TCP stream.

```
CLIENT > TCP SRC 33333 DST 80 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
SERVER < TCP SRC 80 DST 33333 "200 OK"
```

Comment: What if I request 2 files on the same server. Let's say 1.dat, 2.dat. How to know which one 200 OK is for 2.dat?

Comment: @blez - the Client will either use 2 separate sockets with different source ports. If you end up with requests happening from the same source port than the responses will have to come in chronologically so you can use the time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the traffic you can always use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It has a function to "Follow TCP Stream". If you want to program a sniffer, I would suggest lecture of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [justniffer](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net/). it is extendible by scripts. a new version not yes released in [trunk](http://sourceforge.net/p/justniffer/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) branch of repository is extedible by python.